# discord.js | Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making my command handler in discord.js v12, and I keep on getting this error, which is:

> Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Here is my code, this code is in a folder called `handlers`

```js
const { readdirSync, readdir } = require('fs');
const ascii = require('ascii-table');
let table = new ascii('commands');

table.setHeading('Commands', 'Status');

module.exports = (client) => {
 readdirSync('./commands/').forEach((dir) => {
  const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter((file) =>
   file.endsWith('.js')
  );
  for (let file of commands) {
   let pull = require(`../commands/${dir}/${file}`);
   if (pull.name) {
    client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);

    table.addRow(file, '✅');
   } else {
    table.addRow(
     file,
     `❌ -> Missing a help.name, or help.name in not a string.`
    );
    continue;
   }
   if (pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases))
    pull.aliases.forEach((alias) => client.aliases.set(aliases, pull.name));
  }
 });
 console.log(table.toString());
};
```

In my entry point, which is `main.js`, I have made a new collection.

Comment: Did you define `client.commands`?

Comment: Well, client.commands is undefined, I don't think you can effectively add something to custom defined properties

Comment: I did define client.command in my entry point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your working in a separate file so you haven't got access to the variables defined in the other

to get around this, in you main.js file you need to use a `module.exports.client = client` and the in the handler.js file you can do `const client = require("../main.js").client`

You must also make sure that when defining `client.commands` you give it the correct object type. It must be `client.commands = new Discord.Collection()`